# Change cursor offset windows

Tags: windows, cursor

I want to customize my cursor within windows settings. The problem is when I set it to an ico file, the actual pointer (anchor) is at the top left of my image. I want to have it moved to the center. I looked at some windows defaults, and they seem to have the functionality like the "busy" cursor

for clarity: when I click, it clicks at the red position (left), but I want it to do it in the middle (right)

[image]

Comment: What program are you using to create the .ico file?

Comment: You need to set the cursor hotspot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidPostill states, set the hotspot: the single pixel in an icon image identified as the point on which you clicked. There are various [applications for making your own cursor icon](https://listoffreeware.com/free-cursor-maker-software-windows/), or for modifying an existing one, and many are free.

BTW, save the file with extension *.cur*, or *.ani*, for animated cursors, not as *.ico*.